# Filling 4 Items in a listview on any device

Tags: android, listview, size

I'm developing an application that have to show exactly 4 items at a time in a listview, independent of device.

How do I get the size of the list view on the device and set list items height to fit 4 at a time on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- extend `ListView` class

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView {

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    private Runnable afterLayoutRunnable;

    public void setAfterLayoutRunnable(Runnable afterLayoutRunnable) {
        this.afterLayoutRunnable = afterLayoutRunnable;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        if (afterLayoutRunnable != null) {
            afterLayoutRunnable.run();
        }
    }

}
```

2- create your own `ArrayAdapter`

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject> {
    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<MyObject> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_item_layout, null);
            int height = TestActivity.listItemsMinimumHieght;
            if (height > 0) {
                convertView.setMinimumHeight(height);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

3- in your `Activity`

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    public static int listItemsMinimumHieght = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final CustomListView customListView = (CustomListView) findViewById(R.id.conversation_activity_button_send);
        customListView.setAfterLayoutRunnable(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                listItemsMinimumHieght = customListView.getHeight() / 4;
                ArrayList<MyObject> objects=getListContent();
                customListView.setAdapter(new ListViewConversationAdapter(TestActivity.this, R.id.sample, objects));

            }
        });

    }

}
```

i think this should work, good luck

Comment: if `listItemsMinimumHieght = customListView.getHeight() / 4;` didnt return accurate height, use `listItemsMinimumHieght = customListView.getMeasuredHeight() / 4;`

Comment: It didin't =/ 
But worked a different solution:

ViewTreeObserver vto = getListView().getViewTreeObserver();
  vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onPreDraw() {
    if (firstUpdate){
     chronoItemHeight = getListView().getMeasuredHeight() / 4;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
     
     firstUpdate = false;
    }
    return true;
   }
  });

But thanks for the help!

Comment: @ Filipe,can you edit your the correct answer at the first question location?thank you